# Plot a line half dashed and half solid

Tags: plotting

Hi I'm plotting several curves and want one of them to be dashed when negative and solid when positive, any idea how this can be obtained?

This is what I have so far ( example ):

```
 Plot[{v, v - 10 , v + 10}, {v, -9, 9},PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Dashed,Red], Red}]
```

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Here's a guess, something like `PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Dashed, Red], Red}`?  Or do you want a line to be dashed up to some point and then solid after?  -- What did you mean by "the second and second plots"?

Comment: yes ,say dashed from -9 to 0 and solid from 0 to 9, edited the Q

Comment: How about `Plot[{ConditionalExpression[v, v < 0], ConditionalExpression[v, v >= 0]}, {v, -9, 9}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Dashed], Blue}]`?

Comment: @J.M.isback., like your Comment, pls post as an Answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Agree it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a brute-force approach with [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
Plot[
 {
  Piecewise[{{v, v < 0}}, None], Piecewise[{{v, v >= 0}}, None],
  Piecewise[{{v - 10, v < 0}}, None], 
  Piecewise[{{v - 10, v >= 0}}, None],
  Piecewise[{{v + 10, v < 0}}, None], 
  Piecewise[{{v + 10, v >= 0}}, None]
  },
 {v, -9, 9},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Purple, Dashed], Green, 
   Directive[Blue, Dashed], Pink, Directive[Red, Dashed], Black}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, nicely done. :) As noted, one can also use `ConditionalExpression[]` instead of `Piecewise[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Show[Plot[{v, v - 10, v + 10}, {v, -9, 0}, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Blue], Directive[Dashed, Red], 
Directive[Dashed, Red]}], 
Plot[{v, v - 10, v + 10}, {v, 0, 9}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Red}], 
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a solution, however, I want to obtain this without using Show, I use manipulate and need everything concatenated.

Comment: @jarhead - While you may prefer some other approach/solution, a requirement to use `Manipulate` does not preclude use of `Show`. `Show` is compatible with `Manipulate`.